# Moving uploaded file not working in PHP

Tags: php

I'm using a php script that resizes uploaded images. It works fine but I want to move the resized uploaded images into a particular directory and I just can't get this to work. Can anyone tell me what I've got wrong?

Thanks.

```
<?php
    $name = ''; $type = ''; $size = ''; $error = '';
    function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) {

        $info = getimagesize($source_url);

            if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
                    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);

            elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif')
                    $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);

        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png')
                    $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);

            imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
        return $destination_url;
    }

    if ($_POST) {

            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
                    $error = $_FILES["file"]["error"];
            } 
            else if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || 
            ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || 
            ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || 
            ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) {

                    $url = "mypic.jpg";

                    $filename = compress_image($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $url, 80);

                   //This is where the script stops working
  if (move_uploaded_file($filename, "myFolder/".$url)) {
echo "Completed"
 }else{
     $error = "Uploaded image should be jpg or gif or png";
    echo $error;
 }


            }
  }
?>
```

Comment: What doesnt work? What errors do you see? What is the real path you are working with for the file location and the php script doing it? Side note though, `move_uploaded_file` expects the full path to the unaltered uploaded file location.... so your `compress_image` is most likely causing the issue as its messing with the `tmp_name` file location.

Comment: Well the real destination is a bit different but in an attempt to simply things I have not included that. The error I get is PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end.

Comment: In fact ignore the error, that's from earlier. I don't get an error weirdly.

Comment: Even when you add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script? No warnings or errors at all? And the file isn't being moved to the destination path relative to the php script?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The compress_image function works but the problem seems that once I have done that I cannot identify the image file to download as it is no longer a temporary file.